# Loading image from Cache into detail view controller

Tags: objective-c, image, dropbox-api

I am working on integrating dropbox app in my app. I have downloaded a image in my dropbox app into my cache by doing the following.

```
cachePathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
cachePath = [cachePathArray lastObject];
```

Now I have to display this file that I downloaded in cachePath in my detail view controller. Also when I download some other file, the previous file in cache is getting overridden
. Is there any way where in I can maintain all the files that user downloads ? My job is to download user's images in dropbox folder into my iPad and then display it in detail view controller.

I tried loading the image by using imageWithFileContents of UIImage and I gave it the path. But, it dint work for me.